# 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions | SoFUN & Overflow

Tags: r

I am using the SoFUN & overflow package to try and calculate the median class.

This is the two lines I have been using.

```
MedianMen <- structure(list(Age = c("15-19", "20-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "65-74", "75-84", "84-over"), frequancy = c(130292, 117683, 216706, 278284, 302612, 244425, 202556, 83825, 14486)), .Names = c("Age", "Frequancy"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

This line above gives no errors,

```
GroupedMedian(MedianMen$Age, MedianMen$Frequancy, sep = "-")

Error in rowMeans(intervals) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

However this line above gives this error. I am confused, am I supposed to be identifying the x and y axis or something?

All your help is appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to know but probably GroupedMedian  is directly or indirectly calling rowMeans() and you are not suppplying an array of two dimensions which is what rowMeans needs since it calculates the mean of a row.  What have you tried in order to solve this?

Comment: You can't put "over" only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the function documented here: https://rdrr.io/github/mrdwab/SOfun/man/GroupedMedian.html

Try switching the order, or alternatively labelling frequencies & intervals in your function call:

```
GroupedMedian(MedianMen$Frequancy, MedianMen$Age, sep = "-")

GroupedMedian(intervals = MedianMen$Age, frequencies = MedianMen$Frequancy, sep = "-")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what package the GroupedMedian function came from, but I think this solves the problem:

```
median(rep(MedianMen$Age, MedianMen$Frequency))
```